# Is there a Jenkins code coverage plugin for Perl?

Tags: jenkins, code-coverage, jenkins-plugins

We have our software product which is written in perl. We have setup a Jenkins build for that which runs the automated tests, to get the coverage values we run the unit tests under Devel::Cover, and get the coverage values for each module. But I find it very difficult to go and check the coverge values for each module individually, also it doesn't tell us where are we heading as far as coverage is concerned (increasing/decreasing trend). So what I'd like is to have a history or graph of those values, so that I can have a better picture of where our coverage values are and how do they compare to, say a month ago.
Is there a plug-in available that would do this thing?

I searched the Internet and found some plugins like cobertura and emma that I hope would achieve that purpose, but they are for Java. Is there a good alternative for Perl?

Also, would it be worth it to develop our own tool to display such plots? We already have the coverage data in Jenkins, and all we need is just to get that data and plot it.

Answer (score 0):

You can with luck use Devel::Cover's HTML output formatting, put by default in the *cover_db* directory by:

```
$ cover -test
```

The install and configure the [HTML Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin).

Configure it as so:

```
HTML directory: cover_db
index page: coverage.html
Report title: Coverage Report
```

I written up my notes for setting this up, and they are available at:

https://logiclab.jira.com/wiki/display/OPEN/Continuous+Integration#ContinuousIntegration-CoverageTests

I am currently looking into the Jenkins Plugin Clover, since Devel::Cover can also output in Clover format. I will update my notes soon.

You can with luck use my CPAN distribution Task::Jenkins, installing all of the CPAN dependencies needed for the setup on the referenced wiki page.